# Send more data than what can be stored in send buffer

Tags: c#, sockets, rtsp

I am using C# sockets to implement my own basic RTSP server (for learning purposes).  I am currently in the process of writing the logic for the server to perform the handshake with the client when negotiating media ports on a DESCRIBE request.

The client application was not written by me and I have no access to update the software, it is a simple RTSP client which negotiates media ports on a Cisco router and then pipes audio to clients connected to it.

The payload I want to send back is 1024 bytes and a 64 byte header, and from what I can see from inspecting my client app, only 400 bytes are transmitted back to the client.

The response payload is defined in C# as:

```
// Build the RTSP Response string
var body =      "v=0\n" +
                "o=- 575000 575000 IN IP4 " + m_serverIP + "\n" +
                "s=" + stream + "\n" +
                "i=<No author> <No copyright>\n" + 
                "c= IN IP4 0.0.0.0\n"+
                "t=0 0\n" +
                "a=SdpplinVersion:1610641560\n" +
                "a=StreamCount:integer;1\n" +
                "a=control:*\n" +
                "a=Flags:integer;1\n" +
                "a=HasParam:integer;0\n" +
                "a=LatencyMode:integer;0\n" + 
                "a=LiveStream:integer;1\n" + 
                "a=mr:intgner;0\n" +
                "a=nr:integer;0\n" +
                "a=sr:integer;0\n" + 
                "a=URL:string;\"Streams/" + stream + "\"\n" +
                "a=range:npt=0-\n" + 
                "m=audio 0 RTP/AVP 8" + // 49170 is the RTP transport port and 8 is A-Law audio
                "b=AS:90\n" +
                "b=TIAS:64000\n" +
                "b=RR:1280\n" +
                "b=RS:640\n" + 
                "a=maxprate:50.000000\n" +
                "a=control:streamid=1\n" +
                "a=range:npt=0-\n" +
                "a=length:npt=0\n" +
                "a=rtpmap:8 pcma/8000/1\n" +
                "a=fmtp:8" +
                "a=mimetype:string;\"audio/pcma\"\n" +
                "a=ASMRuleBook:string;\"marker=0, Avera**MSG 00053 TRUNCATED**\n" +
                "**MSG 0053 CONTINUATION #01**geBandwidth=64000, Priority=9, timestampdelivery=true;\"\n" +
                "a=3GPP-Adaptation-Support:1\n" +
                "a=Helix-Adaptation-Support:1\n" +
                "a=AvgBitRate:integer;64000\n" +
                "a=AvgPacketSize:integer;160\n" + 
                "a=BitsPerSample:integer;16\n" +
                "a=LiveStream:integer;1\n" + 
                "a=MaxBitRate:integer;64000\n" +
                "a=MaxPacketSize:integer;160\n" +
                "a=Preroll:integer;2000\n" +
                "a=StartTime:integer;0\n" +
                "a=OpaqueData:buffer;\"AAB2dwAGAAEAAB9AAAAfQAABABAAAA==\""; 

var header =    "RTSP/1.0 200 OK\n" +
                "Content-Length: " + body.Length + "\n" +
                "x-real-usestrackid:1\n" +
                "Content-Type: application/sdp\n" +
                "Vary: User-Agent, ClientID\n" +
                "Content-Base: " + requestURI + "\n" +
                "vsrc:" + m_serverIP + "/viewsource/template.html\n" +
                "Set-Cookie: " + Auth.getCookie() + "\n" +
                "Date: " + System.DateTime.Now + "\n" +
                "CSeq: 0\n";

var response = header + body;

var byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response);
respondToClient(byteArray, socket);
```

The responding method `respondToClient` is implemented as:

```
private static void respondToClient(byte[] byteChunk, Socket socket)
{
    socket.BeginSend(byteChunk, 0, byteChunk.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), socket);
    socket.BeginReceive(m_dataBuffer, 0, m_dataBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), socket);
}
```

With a `SendCallback` to determine when the packet has been sent to the client:

```
private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult res)
{
    try
    {
        var socket = (Socket)res.AsyncState;
        socket.EndSend(res);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.Write(e.Message);
    }
}
```

Why is my client application only receiving 400 bytes, and if so how can I make sure my whole packet is sent (I'm using TCP)? Is this a hard limit set by C#? I consulted MSDN and could not find any information to support this theory.

If there are more details required regarding the implementation of my server, please ask.

**EDIT** Here is some food for thought, and I don't know why it would be happening so if somebody could enlighten me that would be great... @ Gregory A Beamer suggested in the comments that `EndSend` could be firing prematurely, is this a possibility? From my understanding I thought the async callback would only fire once, and only once all bytes had been sent from the server to the listening client socket.

In order for me to tell that the packet wasn't being fully recieved by the client, the following information states that only 400 bytes are received by the client application:

[image]

Supported by a wireshark trace from S->C

[image]

**UPDATE** After speaking earlier with @usr I did some further tests and can now confirm that the client application will only ever receive a 400 byte response back from the server.  I  h

```
Jul  1 13:28:29: //-1//RTSP:/rtsp_read_svr_resp: Socket = 0
Jul  1 13:28:29: //-1//RTSP:/rtsp_read_svr_resp: NBYTES = 1384
Jul  1 13:28:29: //-1//RTSP:/rtsp_process_single_svr_resp:
Jul  1 13:28:29: rtsp_process_single_svr_resp: 400 bytes of data:
RTSP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Length: 1012
x-real-usestrackid:1
Content-Type: application/sdp
Vary: User-Agent, ClientID
Content-Base: rtsp://10.96.134.50/streams/stream01.dcw
vsrc:10.96.134.50/viewsource/template.html
Set-Cookie: cbid=aabtvqjcldwjwjbatynprfpfltxaspyopoccbtewiddxuzhsesflnkzvkwibtikwfhuhhzzz;path=/;expires=09/10/2015 14:28:38
Date: 01/07/2015 14:28:38
CSeq: 0  
v=0
o=- 575000 575000 IN IP4
```

^ This is the log trace dumped by the client application when I dial in to the server, here we can see that it accept 1384 bytes back from the client, but its processing buffer is only capable of storing 400 bytes.  I looked at a log for an existing application which handles streaming to the same device, and in the wireshark trace, instead of sending the header in one block, it sends several chunks back with the info `[TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]` I am not sure what this means (new to network stuff) but I assume its breaking down the server payload and sending it over in several chunks and then reassembling on the client to handle the request.

How can I replicate this behaviour on my server application? I tried the following in my respond method, with hopes that it would pipe back the packet and reassemble on the client, however I just continued to get the same error discussed above:

```
private static void respondToClient(byte[] byteChunk, Socket socket)
{
    // Divide the byte chunk into 300 byte chunks
    if (byteChunk.Length >= 400)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Total bytes: " + byteChunk.Length);

        var totalBytes = byteChunk.Length;
        var chunkSize = 400;
        var tmp = new byte[chunkSize];

        var packets  = totalBytes / chunkSize;
        var overflow = totalBytes % chunkSize;

        Console.WriteLine("Sending " + totalBytes + " in " + packets + " packets, with an overflow packets of " + overflow + " bytes.");

        for (var i = 0; i < packets * chunkSize; i+=chunkSize)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sending chunk " + i + " to " + (i + chunkSize));
            tmp = byteChunk.Skip(i).Take(chunkSize).ToArray();
            socket.BeginSend(tmp, 0, tmp.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), socket);
        }
        if (overflow > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sending overflow chunk: " + overflow + " at index " + (totalBytes - overflow) + " to " + (totalBytes ));
            tmp = byteChunk.Skip(byteChunk.Length - overflow).Take(overflow).ToArray();
            socket.BeginSend(tmp, 0, tmp.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), socket);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        socket.BeginSend(byteChunk, 0, byteChunk.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), socket);
        socket.BeginReceive(m_dataBuffer, 0, m_dataBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), socket);
    }
}
```

Comment: send method limit is System.Int32

Comment: I see, how can I ensure the entire packet is sent?

Comment: Are you getting an exception?  I also see that your `a=fmtp:8` line has no newline at the end of it

Comment: What does the client implementation look like? It could be causing the EndSend to fire too early. Just an idea.

Comment: Getting no exceptions, I'll try and add the new line nice spot.. However on the client it only prints out to `v=0`

Comment: @GregoryABeamer I dont have access to the client app, its a Cisco router with a small script on it to negotiate the RTSP handshake, interesting thought that the end send is firing early, that definitely could be what is happening

Comment: Left-field notion...any chance of a duplex mismatch between the client and the server?

Comment: @DavidW thanks for your comments - what exactly is a Duplex Mistmatch? As noted above, networking stuff is new to me!

Comment: A duplex mismatch is where one side of a conversation can simultaneously send traffic both ways, but the other end can only go one way at a time. A normal symptom of this might be an otherwise inexplicably slow connection, but I was wildly speculating maybe the failure to capture more than those 400 bytes might be indicative of it not syncing up properly with the other side, eg duplex mismatch. Probably a crazy, wrong idea, just tossing out of the box notions out there for you. Interesting problem!

Comment: Thanks for the idea David, I'll look more into it as it may shine some light on the problem!  However, it seems weird that running the same test multiple times with multiple or one clients connected would result in a constant results of 400 bytes being collected on the client.  Thanks for your input :)

Comment: `"a=mr:intgner;0\n" +` -- integer is spelled wrong

Comment: Thanks @JoePhilllips, made the change, unfortunately wasn't the bug ;)

Comment: Can you record with wireshark the working connection and then replay the data to the device packet by packet? There are .NET wrappers around the .pcap format where you can get the tcp packet payload and replay to the device the raw data. If the device is so simple it could be that its implementation of the TCP stack is simply faulty and imposes additional limits not written in any standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may seem controversial, but the bug in the code was extremely silly and I have to attribute the success of this question to @Keyz182 in the answers.  After discussing privately he noticed that I was using `\n` to add new line elements.

The problem was I needed to change these returns to `\r\n` and add one between the header and the body to dictate to the client where the header ended and the body information of the payload started (smacks head against brick wall).

It turns out that there was no 400 byte buffer on the client (so I am still amused as to why it talked about a processing buffer of 400 bytes). Thank-you all for your help!

Comment: It may have been the size of the buffer allocated to read a single line. As it wasn't seeing the CRLF it was expecting, it just kept reading until the buffer was full, before realising that it was an invalid line, at which point it just abruptly closed the connection.

Comment: @Keyz182 that does make total sense now you say it - I always miss the small details...thanks again for your help

Answer (score 2):

TCP is a boundaryless stream of bytes. There are no packets perceivable to applications. Read/Receive calls return any number of bytes in a non-deterministic way (at least one). In the receiver you must deal with the fact that reads can be partial. Use the return value of Receive to determine the number of bytes received.

This is all easier if you read synchronously and use `BinaryReader` because it does this looping logic for you.

> BeginSend could be firing prematurely, is this a possibility

No.

Comment: Sorry I meant `EndSend` but I assume the answer is still no (as I thought).  The only problem I have with this application is I have no control over the client, its a SIP device and the client software cannot be modified (makes my job a little harder).  Is there any way I can ensure on the server app that all bytes are transmitted to the listening socket?

Comment: OK. First let's note that the client is broken. You should be able to make a single TCP packet go out by disabling Nagling and performing exactly one BeginSend call. Use Wireshark to confirm that the TCP packet leaves with the expected 1024+64 bytes of data. This is a hack mind you.; Btw, how did you determine that the client only receives part of the data?

Comment: I have updated my question with a wireshark trace and a log from the client app

Comment: I don't know how to debug this further. The Wireshark trace does not show anything like a packet with 400 bytes.

Comment: I'm seeing the `1461` byte packet as the troublesome one, the client does respond with an acknowledgment, but it seems that it only accept 400 bytes on the client - maybe I should do a loop in the send method and pipe 400 bytes at a time or something, see if that works...it just seems very bizarre (I guess the client could have a max 400byte buffer on its end, that would make sense...bad architecture though?!)

Comment: What client software is this?

Comment: It's being used for a telephony application, its a Cisco router that establishes the media ports via RTSP and then spits audio to its connected clients.  I guess having a small receiving buffer could make sense in this scenario?    That's all of the implementation details I have been given though

Comment: Given that messages appear to be frequently bigger than 400 bytes I kind of doubt that the client can't handle this. I still think the bug is yours but I can't spot any problem. Maybe there is a bug in some code that is not visible here and you're simply sending the wrong stuff. Look into the Wireshark packets ("follow TCP stream") and make sure the contents are right.

Comment: In the TCP stream, the whole packet is there, I just updated my question

Comment: We are making progress it seems. I am not in the mood to think through that complicated chunking logic there... Use Wireshark to make sure it works. Make sure to disable Nagling. Else, the TCP stack will merge those writes together.

Comment: I too think the chunking logic seem a little bloated for what I am trying to achieve.  I will keep digging through packets!

Comment: Any details about the Cisco router available? Could the router be doing some sort of filtering or inspection that stops at a 400-byte boundary??

Answer (score 2):

A possible answer may be that the client has set a specific block size in it's request to your server (See 12.7 - https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2326.txt). That may or may not be applicable, but if you could dump out the request that the client sends you and look through that, you may see a blocksize stated somewhere around the 400 mark.

**EDIT:** Check Alex' answer below for the final answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I spent a lot of time scouring the RFC documentation, but I do agree that there must be some sort of soft cap on the client.  It's just annoying how the client application is a black box with 0 documentation!